# Union query through case

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

My data looks like this

```
ID   Source Destination FLAG

1    A      B           Y

2    C      D           N
```

Resultant data is based on below logic

if FLAG='Y' then resultant query will lhave two rows with source and destination columns swaped else only one row

```
ID   Source Destination FLAG

1    A      B            Y

1    B      A            Y

2    C      D            N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be quite easy task to jumble the columns, and it should work. However, if you still insist to use case, then :

```
SQL> WITH data
  2       AS (SELECT 1   id,
  3                  'A' source,
  4                  'B' destination,
  5                  'Y' flag
  6           FROM   dual
  7           UNION ALL
  8           SELECT 2   id,
  9                  'C' source,
 10                  'D' destination,
 11                  'N' FLAG
 12           FROM   dual)
 13  SELECT *
 14  FROM  (SELECT id,
 15                source,
 16                destination,
 17                flag
 18         FROM   data
 19         UNION ALL
 20         SELECT id,
 21                CASE
 22                  WHEN flag = 'Y' THEN destination
 23                END AS "source",
 24                CASE
 25                  WHEN flag = 'Y' THEN source
 26                END AS "destination",
 27                flag
 28         FROM   data)
 29  WHERE  source IS NOT NULL
 30         AND destination IS NOT NULL
 31  ORDER  BY id
 32
SQL> /
```

Result:

```
        ID S D F
---------- - - -
         1 A B Y
         1 B A Y
         2 C D N
```

Answer (score 3):

i think u don't need `case` in this fall, just change the places of source and destination where the Flag is `'Y'` and add it to the original table filtered by `id`.

```
select id, source, destination, flag from table_name
union
select id, destination, source, flag from table_name
where flag = 'Y'
order by id
```